# How to get monthly list for All Employees?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a table with below structure:

| Id | CreatedOn | Name |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2023-04-12 | Mark |
| 2 | 2023-04-28 | Luke |
| 3 | 2023-05-15 | Nina |
| 4 | 2023-05-29 | Karl |
| 5 | 2023-06-17 | Kara |
| 6 | 2023-06-30 | Jack |

From this table I want to create below **View** (Denoting How the Table looked like as on End of a Particular Month)  :

| Id | CreatedOn | Name | Month |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2023-04-12 | Mark | 2023-04-30 |
| 2 | 2023-04-28 | Luke | 2023-04-30 |
| 1 | 2023-04-12 | Mark | 2023-05-31 |
| 2 | 2023-04-28 | Luke | 2023-05-31 |
| 3 | 2023-05-15 | Nina | 2023-05-31 |
| 4 | 2023-05-29 | Karl | 2023-05-31 |
| 1 | 2023-04-12 | Mark | 2023-06-30 |
| 2 | 2023-04-28 | Luke | 2023-06-30 |
| 3 | 2023-05-15 | Nina | 2023-06-30 |
| 4 | 2023-05-29 | Karl | 2023-06-30 |
| 5 | 2023-06-17 | Kara | 2023-06-30 |
| 6 | 2023-06-30 | Jack | 2023-06-30 |

Currently I have created a new table for this and Inserting data after end of every month but wanted to know if a view can be created for this.

Here's a script to create the above table:

```
CREATE TABLE Employees (
    Id INT,
    CreatedOn DATE,
    Name VARCHAR(50)
);

INSERT INTO Employees (Id, CreatedOn, Name)
VALUES
    (1, '2023-04-12', 'Mark'),
    (2, '2023-04-28', 'Luke'),
    (3, '2023-05-15', 'Nina'),
    (4, '2023-05-29', 'Karl'),
    (5, '2023-06-17', 'Kara'),
    (6, '2023-06-30', 'Jack');
```

Comment: did you try to create a view that generates the monthly list for all employees

Comment: I tried but I am only able to generate for a particular month. I want monthly data for all of the previous months as well which I am able to do when I insert it into a separate table but I want to create a view so that I wouldn't need the extra table.

Comment: then try using a recursive Common Table Expression (CTE) to generate the list

Comment: What is your problem: Finding the end of the month for a date or regenerating those rows for multiple month, or even both?

Comment: The main problem is to regenerate those rows for every month

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See comments in the code for explanation.

```
-- This will create date for every month between the given dates
WITH dates AS (
    SELECT CAST('2023-04-01' AS DATETIME) DateValue
    UNION ALL
    SELECT DATEADD(month, 1, datevalue)
    FROM dates   
    WHERE DATEADD(month, 1, datevalue) <= '2023-06-30'
)
-- Join the employees with the dates on the condition
-- that the createdon date must be less than or equal to the last of the month
SELECT id, createdon, name, EOMONTH(datevalue)
FROM employees
INNER JOIN dates ON createdon <= EOMONTH(datevalue)
ORDER BY datevalue, id;
```

Answer (score -2):

For finding which month created

```
SELECT DATEPART(MONTH,CreatedOn) AS MONTH
FROM yourTable
```

For finding the last day of month in SQL Server

```
SELECT EOMONTH(CreatedOn)
FROM yourTable
```

This will return the last day. for example `SELECT EOMONTH('2024-02-14')`  this return `2024-02-29`

Making view

```
CREATE VIEW viewName
AS
SELECT
    Id,
    CreatedOn,
    [Name],
    EOMONTH(CreatedOn) AS [Month]
FROM yourTable
```

Comment: But this view won't be able to give month wise data

Comment: @qudsif can you explain what do you need exactly. In your example I saw this

Comment: @Mervan I need April's data in May, June and future Months as well. For every new month all of the previous month's data should be included. derpirscher's Answer solves this

Comment: okay I understand now. I will edit it as view. Because it cannot be a view. Maybe procedure

Comment: Whats with the MySQL solution? Question is tagged SQL Server.